Simulating an alphanumeric client keyboard display Behavior in a html Textarea
I'm building a code editor using a textarea element and I'd like to achieve the following behavior:
The keyboard should primarily display alphanumeric keys, similar to how an input type="password" works.
I want to prevent the keyboard from suggesting completions or auto-correcting the input.
I've tried using the inputmode="verbatim" attribute, but it doesn't seem to control the keyboard layout or suppress suggestions.
<textarea autocomplete="off" inputmode="verbatim"></textarea>




This just prevents auto-completes, auto-corrects, and spellcheckings.
<textarea autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" inputmode="verbatim"></textarea>

